# Add additional Google login on web using firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-google-login

Can anyone help to give some detail advice, how to add google login and pass authentication on firebase?

On the mobile app, there is a google login button for registration and I already have a google account in firebase. Just need a google button for the web app.

This is the form for the general username and password login:

```
private submitForm = async(e: any) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (validateForm(this)) {
    const st = this.state;
    const model = {
      email: st.email.value,
      password: st.password.value
    };
    this.setState({
      showLoader: true
    });
    firebase.app().auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(model.email, model.password).then(async(result: any) => {
      if (result) {
        const userDetail = await getVendorDetail({
          uid: result.user.uid
        });
        if (userDetail && userDetail.status === 200) {
          if (userDetail && userDetail.data.role === "user") {
            this.setState({
              showLoader: false
            });
            setStorage(CONSTANT.keys.token, userDetail.data.token);
            setStorage(CONSTANT.keys.userDetail, {
              uid: userDetail.data.uid,
              displayName: userDetail.data.displayName,
              email: userDetail.data.email,
              photoURL: userDetail.data.photoURL
            });
            if (userDetail.data.isVendorPlanSubscribed) {
              window.location.href = CONSTANT.url.dashboard;
            }
          } else {
            this.setState({
              showLoader: false
            });
            toast.error("You are not authorized to login");
          }
        } else if (userDetail && userDetail.status === 400) {
          this.setState({
            showLoader: false
          });
          toast.error(userDetail.message);
        }
      }
    }).catch((error: any) => {
      this.setState({
        showLoader: false
      });
      if (error && error.code === "auth/user-not-found") {
        toast.error(error.message);
      }
      if (error && error.code === "auth/wrong-password") {
        toast.error(error.message);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This is the code I have so far. I'm not sure what to add here:

```
private googleLogin() {
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then(async(result: any) => {
      const user = result.user;
      console.log(user);
    })
    .catch(console.log)
}
```

On the mobile app, there is a google login button for registration and I already have a google account in firebase. Just need a google button for the web app.

The google login window popped up. and I put the account and password in and that's it.

Comment: I have already signup with a google account using the mobile app.  And the account is already in the firebase firestore. Just want to know how to implement the Google login on the web app.

Answer (score 0):

Idea is pretty simple, you requested google to authenticate user from your app, once authentication is successful with google popup(i.e. oauth) it will send token and user details in the success response.

That's what you receive in your user variable, now its a go ahead from google, now you can redirect your user to whatever screen you want them to see. if there is issue with authentication it will throw error, also you can use this token to use any google services.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Could you give some code examples please. I'm still a bit confused. I can see the console log with the "uid" and "refresh tokens". But not sure how to use it with the firebase.

Comment: What's your next logic after login?

Comment: Just I cannot log in. But I can see I passed the google login. 
I have a general username and password to login to the web app. But I need login into the web app using google login as well. Already have a google account in firebase. But not sure what to do with the backend.

Comment: You are using Google login for client side. Now your backend doesn't know about this user so I recommend you register the user by sending a request to server or login the user and get an authentication token.

Comment: If your web app uses firebase authentication, then you can directly call authentication like mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72845747/firebase-authentication-using-google-facebook-with-custom-nodejs-server